# xmlpullparserexception expected: START_TAG

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have the following:

```
public String searchRecipes( String searchString, int pageNumber ) throws Exception
    {
        SoapObject _client = new SoapObject( "", "searchRecipes" );
        _client.addProperty("searchString", searchString);
        _client.addProperty("pageNumber",   pageNumber);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope _envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER11 );
        _envelope.bodyOut = _client;

        Marshal dateMarshal = new MarshalDate();
        dateMarshal.register(_envelope);

        HttpTransportSE _ht = new HttpTransportSE(Configuration.getWsUrl());
        _ht.call("", _envelope);

        return  _envelope.getResponse().toString();
    }
```

It works fine when I use it on my local server on the PC using the eclipse.
But when I deploy it I get:

```
expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4056fb48)
```

Can anybody help? I am facing it for more than a week.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think NAMESPACE string should be the first argument in SoapObject constructor. The same for the call() method (here should be NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME as the first parameter)

And try this:

```
_envelope.setOutputSoapObject(_client);
```

instead of this:

```
_envelope.bodyOut = _client;
```

To get the response: it depends on what your web service is returning (a primitive or complex object?)