# Android exception org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG

Tags: android, wcf

I have been trying to consume a .NET webservic

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ICustomers/getAllProductsDT";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getAllProductsDT";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://10.121.11.53/Customers/Customers.svc";




SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransportSE.debug=true;
androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
String str= soapEnvelope.getResponse().toString();
```

my first log doesn't show up in the logcat and for the second one I catched the following excpetion :

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e56bb0) 

05-14 16:08:28.573: W/System.err(3532): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e56bb0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288356/xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag

Comment: 05-14 16:08:28.573: W/System.err(3532): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e56bb0)

Answer (score 1):

Its not a problem with android or WebService.

There might be an app_html.offline in APPCODE which doesnt allow it to run online.

Go to Solution Explorer in C#.

Rightclick and Exclude it from project. :D

**AND**

You should have below format to consume .net web service in android using ksoap.

> ```
>    private static final String URL = "http://....asmx"; // Make sure that the url is end with .asmx
>    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://domain.com"; // It may contain "/" at the of name space. Because it's your name space.
>    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "UserLogin"; // Method Name
>    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://domain.com/UserLogin"; // Domain and method name.
> ```

Just you need to follow above structure.