# SOAP org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm try call web-method "Registration" from web Service. It contain  one input parameter and one output.

```
HttpTransportSE  httpTransport=null;

        try 
        {
            String organization = "Слоник Зеленый";

            String method = "Registration";
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://www.ServiceDesk.org", method);

            PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi1.setName("Organisation");
            pi1.setValue(organization);
            pi1.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi1);



            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //VER.10,VER.11,VER.12 don't help
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
//          envelope.implicitTypes = true;  #don't help me

            envelope.dotNet = false; # "true" value don't help
            List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("user:password".getBytes())));


            httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(MainAsync.wsdlSchema);

            httpTransport.debug=true;
            httpTransport.call("http://www.ServiceDesk.org#ServiceDesk:Registration", envelope,headerList);

            SoapObject result =(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            String roleId = result.getProperty("return").toString();

            httpTransport.reset();

            return roleId;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(httpTransport.responseDump);
            Log.e("Request "+httpTransport.requestDump);

            e.printStackTrace();
            if(httpTransport!=null)
                httpTransport.reset();
            return"";
        } finally{
            if(httpTransport!=null)
                httpTransport.reset();
        }
```

But om nethod call, i'm get next error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions name='ServiceDesk' targetNamespace='http://www.ServiceDesk.org'>@9:48 in java.io.InputStreamReader@76ed5528) 
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:242)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:1384)
    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:128)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:275)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
```

This is my wsdl file:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap12bind="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapbind="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.ServiceDesk.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://www.ServiceDesk.org" name="ServiceDesk" targetNamespace="http://www.ServiceDesk.org">
<types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs1="http://www.ServiceDesk.org" targetNamespace="http://www.ServiceDesk.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Registration">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Organisation" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</types>
<message name="RegistrationRequestMessage">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:Registration"/>
</message>
<message name="RegistrationResponseMessage">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:RegistrationResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="ServiceDeskPortType">
<operation name="Registration">
<input message="tns:RegistrationRequestMessage"/>
<output message="tns:RegistrationResponseMessage"/>
</operation>
<binding name="ServiceDeskSoapBinding" type="tns:ServiceDeskPortType">
<soapbind:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="Registration">
<soapbind:operation style="document" soapAction="http://www.ServiceDesk.org#ServiceDesk:Registration"/>
<input>
<soapbind:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soapbind:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding-name>
<service name="ServiceDesk">
<port name="ServiceDeskSoap" binding="tns:ServiceDeskSoapBinding">
<documentation>
<wsi:Claim xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/schemas/conformanceClaim/" conformsTo="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1"/>
</documentation>
<soapbind:address location="http://volga.rarus.ru/abc2009_artur/ru/ws/ServiceDesk"/>
</port>
<port name="ServiceDeskSoap12" binding="tns:ServiceDeskSoap12Binding">
<soap12bind:address location="http://volga.rarus.ru/abc2009_artur/ru/ws/ServiceDesk"/>
</port>
</service>
```

I'm parse stackoverflow on similar questions, but it don't help me.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? the same issue I'm facing whenever I have credentials for the call. In case the call didn't need credentials the issue is not surfacing.

Answer (score 2):

i tried this and was correct for me :

Well, I think NAMESPACE string should be the first argument in SoapObject constructor. The same for the call() method (here should be NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME as the first parameter)

And try this:

```
_envelope.setOutputSoapObject(_client);
```

instead of this:

```
_envelope.bodyOut = _client;
```

To get the response: it depends on what your web service is returning (a primitive or complex object?)

Answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288356/xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag):